# Useing Subclipse repository view to check out a branch

Tags: svn, subclipse

I'm want to use subclipse to create a project from code in an SVN branch.  I select 'checkout' from the branch in the repository view. Eventually I get a popup that contains a checkbox labeled:  `Check out HEAD revision`.  I don't want the HEAD I want the Branch.  Since I selected checkout on the branch I'm puzzled as to what I'm being asked to select.  To phrase this as an answerable question: What do I check/uncheck on this screen if I want to checkout a branch project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this chapter of the book:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.basic.svn-repositories

You do not understand the revision model.  HEAD simply means the most recent revision.  Revisions in SVN are global and describe the entire repository.  A branch is a path within the repository.  It would be perfectly normal to checkout HEAD of a branch.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mark for taking the  time to answer.  I was actually asking what Subclipse was prompting for since 'branch' was not mentioned in the prompt.  I'm still  not sure what the prompt means given that I was trying  to  check out  a branch.  In any case I went ahead and did a checkout from the branch in the repository view and I got the branch code.

So to paraphrase Marks' reply, Subclipse is asking whether you want the HEAD or some revision OF THE BRANCH.